# Soundcloud 3.0.0 javascript sdk and FFT/waveforms from streaming object

Tags: javascript, fft, soundcloud, soundmanager2

I am interested in upgrading my project to version 3 of the javascript soundcloud sdk (currently I'm using 2) but an integral part of my project is getting the data that the soundmanager object returned, while streaming.

I've read that theyve moved away from soundmanager, and I was wondering what type of object it does now return and whether I can still get that similar data?

P.S I'm interested in moving, because it seemed like events like seeking used to break the soundmanager objects, because of some authentication issue.

Comment: afaik html5 audio object

Comment: can you add your v2 code to show whats different and not working in v3?